# Hard drive error rate

Tags: hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu and am loving it. The only issue that seems to persist is a bit of a (very soft) scratching sound coming from my HDD. I checked my drive manager and it appears to have a high read error rate. Is this a major issue? The software said any value other than 0 "indicates a problem with the disk or the read/write heads."

Here's a quick screenie for reference: [image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw value for the read rate is meaningless, and basically all drives show really big numbers there.  The normalized value of 118 with a threadhold value of 6 indicates that it is a LONG way from being a problem indicator ( it has to get from 118 down to 6, and the worst it has ever been is 99 ).  This is why the assessment column reports that it is ok.

So, there is nothing wrong with this drive, at least based on that value.

Comment: Okay. Totally agree with you. After Andrea's answer I did some more extensive research and it turns out it's not uncommon to have large values there for non-SSD drives, though I have made backups of my files just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reply to your message at 6 mins ago.

I could suggest the followin external drive, which I use myself:

Toshiba 1 TB stor.e plus
costs are at about 40 until 80 € here in Germany.

This external drive has usb 3.0-connection and does not need external power-cable! It receives its power directly from your computer. So there is no power-waste.

I also read in your profile, that your internal drive already starts to make light scratching noices. This is an alarming-signal, that your hdd is on dying down and that there is no way to save your hdd!!

You should really hurry up with buying an external device, for example the one I sugested and then hurry with doeing a backup of your complete data!!

And as the others already said it correctly: there is absolutely no way to save your internal hdd!!

Greetings
Andrea

Answer (score -1):

I looked at these figures (your disc has a pretty high error-rate) and I really say: this is an issue. If I were you, I would have an eye on that and I would hurry with buying a new external drive and I would do a data-backup as soon as possible.

It cannot be said clearly, how long your internal disc will survive.

Greetings
Andrea

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that. Do you have any solutions that may save the drive? If not, buying an external drive would my last option. Also, would an external drive connected via USB be as fast as my internal drive? Thanks for your help!

Comment: First, no there is no way to save your hard drive. It will fail at any time with no notice and complete data loss. Second, back up your data. Third, in general, a external drive is likely to be slower and more expensive then an internal drive, but, of course, "it depends".

Comment: Okay. Darn! Well I'll start looking for external drives and will make sure to backup my data. Just out of curiosity, though, what would have caused this? I have had the same HDD for a year with no issues and the only thing that changed was a slight scraping noise after I installed Ubuntu 14.04, but only during read/write operations. I'm totally new to Linux.

Comment: Negative ghostrider, there is nothing wrong with this drive.